# Maintaining an object through activity re-creations, e.g. in headless fragment, when "Do not keep activities" on

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

My activity needs to display the Android photo/document select dialog, and so receives an instance of `ValueCallback<Uri[]>` in [onShowFileChooser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)), which I store in an instance variable for later use. When the system-wide setting "Do not keep activities" is on, by the time I need to reference this once the select dialog is gone, it has been killed off. I can't save it to the Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState` because it is not `Serializable` or `Parcelable`. I tried associating a headless Fragment with my activity and storing the reference in there, but I think it was subject to that same killing off inside that activity, thought the Fragment itself hung around successfully. Is there any way I can store off this kind of object so it can persist between Activity re-creations?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState()` is the only way to persist things across Activity death and recreation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant onSaveInstanceState. Updated original question.